# Netsuite - how to specify record_type for getall request

Tags: soap, wsdl, netsuite

I want to get a list of all InventoryItems 
According to this document: 
https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/Output/Help/SuiteCloudCustomizationScriptingWebServices/SuiteTalkWebServices/getAll.html

I'm forming the following request:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:platform_2013_1.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header>
        <passport>
            <email>******</email>
            <password>******</password>
            <account>******</account>
        </passport>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <platformMsgs:getAll>
            <recordType>InventoryItem</recordType>
        </platformMsgs:getAll>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

But receiving response with the error:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <platformMsgs:documentInfo xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <platformMsgs:nsId>WEBSERVICES_969904_100920131651936419141601801_cbf1690968b43</platformMsgs:nsId>
        </platformMsgs:documentInfo>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <getAllResponse xmlns="urn:platform_2013_1.webservices.netsuite.com">
          <platformCore:getAllResult xmlns:platformCore="urn:core_2013_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
              <platformCore:status isSuccess="false">
                  <platformCore:statusDetail type="ERROR">
                      <platformCore:code>GETALL_RCRD_TYPE_REQD</platformCore:code>
                      <platformCore:message>The getAll record type is required.</platformCore:message>
                  </platformCore:statusDetail>
              </platformCore:status>
          </platformCore:getAllResult>
      </getAllResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've tried to request currencies, states - the response always the same

I've tried following variants:

```
<GetAllRecordType>inventoryItem</GetAllRecordType>
```

and

```
<recordType>inventoryItem</recordType>
```

and

```
<GetAllRecordType>currency</GetAllRecordType>
```

and

```
<recordType>currency</recordType>
```

with the same response:

```
 <platformCore:message>The getAll record type is required.</platformCore:message>
```

According to https://webservices.netsuite.com/xsd/platform/v2013_2_0/coreTypes.xsd - I've specified correctly recordType (btw I've also tried  without any success)

I'm using ruby and there is no complete library for ruby. The one that is exists doesn't contain almost all things I'm going to use.

Can someone help me what I'm doing wrong or may be someone have working example

Answer (score 5):

getAll cannot be used for all record types. Here is what is supported via getAll:

budgetCategory

campaignAudience

campaignCategory

campaignChannel

campaignFamily

campaignOffer

campaignSearchEngine

campaignSubscription

campaignVertical

costCategory

currency

leadSource

salesTaxItem

state

supportCaseIssue

supportCaseOrigin

supportCasePriority

supportCaseStatus

supportCaseType

taxGroup

taxType

Answer (score 2):

The most complete implementation of SuiteTalk in Ruby is the [netsuite ruby gem](https://github.com/revolutionprep/netsuite).

It doesn't yet support `ItemSearchAdvanced` (note that unlike most NetSuite records there isn't a `ItemSearchBasic`). Also, note that there isn't a `InventoryItemAdvancedSearch`, `NonInventoryItemAdvancedSearch`, etc like you would expect. Take a look at the `lists.accounting.xsd` for more information in the [schema browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/SchemaBrowser/indexv2012_2_0.html).

Like someone else mentioned, there is no `getAll` call for item record types. The best (and possibly only) way to get all of the items in a NetSuite instance is do a paginate through a search and combine all of the results.

I've coded a [quick hack](https://github.com/iloveitaly/netsuite/tree/item-search-hack) to demonstrate what needs to be done in order to implement item searching in the NetSuite gem. I wouldn't use the referenced hack in production, but could you easily integrate item searching into the NetSuite gem using the info the above referenced hack.

Below is searching code that, when used in combination with the above hack, will get you all of the items in your NetSuite instance.

```
item_list = []
item_search = NetSuite::Records::InventoryItem.search(
  criteria: {
    basic: [

    ]
  },

  preferences: {
    page_size: 100,
  }
)

item_search.results_in_batches do |batch|
  item_list += batch
end
```

*(the above code will probably break if the search returns a `NonInventoryItem` or another item record that isn't a `InventoryItem`, but this should be enough to get you started)*

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this question with the same issue as

```
<platformCore:message>The getAll record type is required.</platformCore:message>
```

Figured I would come post a snippet of what a proper soap envelope should look like for this request.  As others have mentioned, this call only supports certain record types...but once you identify the record type you desire, the below code should help.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:platformFaults="urn:faults_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="urn:platform_2014_1.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <passport>
            <email>test@example.com</email>
            <password>*******</password>
            <account>AccountNumber</account>
            <role internalId="3"/>
        </passport>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <platformMsgs:getAll xmlns="urn:messages_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <platformMsgs:record recordType="currency"/>
        </platformMsgs:getAll>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Also we are using the [**node-soap**](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) module to communicate with this web service and here is what it looks like from that perspective as well.

```
soap.createClient(this.url, function (err, client) {
            client.addSoapHeader({
                passport: {
                    email: 'test@example.com',
                    password: 'pass',
                    account: 'Acct Number',
                    role: {
                        attributes: { internalId: 3 }
                    }
                }
            });
            client.getAll({
                "record": {
                  "attributes": {
                    "recordType": "currency"
                    }
                 }
           }, callback);
        });
});
```

Anyways I hope this helps others as it did stump me for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

inventoryItem, not InventoryItem.

Also, what language are you using? If PHP, there is a PHPToolkit to help you out.

Comment: I've tried:
 <GetAllRecordType>inventoryItem</GetAllRecordType>
and
 <recordType>inventoryItem</recordType>

with the same response:

  <platformCore:message>The getAll record type is required.</platformCore:message>

Answer (score 1):

As Dave suggested, the request will be case-sensitive, so make sure the value you use matches exactly what the XSD says.

If you scroll down the XSD further, you will see the enumeration for `GetAllRecordType` instead of just `RecordType`. This does not have an entry for `inventoryItem` or anything similar, so Inventory Items are most likely not available in this type of request.

You may instead have to build an Item search with no filters to return all Inventory Items.

Comment: I've tried GetAllRecordType enumerator instead of RecordType without any luck

Comment: My point was that there is no `<GetAllRecordType>inventoryItem</GetAllRecordType>`; it doesn't exist, so you'd need to build a custom `<ItemSearch>` instead of using `<getAll>`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone using PHP and specially [this library](https://github.com/ryanwinchester/netsuite-php) you can specify the record type this way:

```
$getAllRequest = new GetAllRequest();
$getAllRequest->record = new GetAllRecord();
$getAllRequest->record->recordType = RecordType::currency;
$getAllResponse = $service->getAll($getAllRequest);
```

This for example returns list of all the existing currencies.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link is helpful :  http://tellsaqib.github.io/NSPHP-Doc/df/d09/class_get_all_record_type.html
    GetAllRecordType Class don't have InventoryItem
  Data Fields
const   budgetCategory = "budgetCategory"

const   campaignAudience = "campaignAudience"

const   campaignCategory = "campaignCategory"

const   campaignChannel = "campaignChannel"

const   campaignFamily = "campaignFamily"

const   campaignOffer = "campaignOffer"

const   campaignSearchEngine = "campaignSearchEngine"

const   campaignSubscription = "campaignSubscription"

const   campaignVertical = "campaignVertical"

const   costCategory = "costCategory"

const   currency = "currency"

const   leadSource = "leadSource"

const   salesTaxItem = "salesTaxItem"

const   state = "state"

const   supportCaseIssue = "supportCaseIssue"

const   supportCaseOrigin = "supportCaseOrigin"

const   supportCasePriority = "supportCasePriority"

const   supportCaseStatus = "supportCaseStatus"

const   supportCaseType = "supportCaseType"

const   taxGroup = "taxGroup"

const   taxType = "taxType"