# Get all Record types from NetSuite

Tags: netsuite

How to get all the supported record types in NetSuite using SuiteTalk?

Description: I need a list of all the record types(Objects)supported in a netsuite account.
I am trying to integrate netsuite and another tool using java.

The operations supported as per the WSDL file, do not have any provision to fetch all record types.

Answer (score 3):

I answered this on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19275153/netsuite-how-to-specify-record-type-for-getall-request/25873331#25873331) and thought I would update it here as well...

I stumbled upon this question with the same issue as

```
<platformCore:message>The getAll record type is required.</platformCore:message>
```

Figured I would come post a snippet of what a proper soap envelope should look like for this request.  As others have mentioned, this call only supports certain record types...but once you identify the record type you desire, the below code should help.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:platformFaults="urn:faults_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="urn:platform_2014_1.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <passport>
            <email>test@example.com</email>
            <password>*******</password>
            <account>AccountNumber</account>
            <role internalId="3"/>
        </passport>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <platformMsgs:getAll xmlns="urn:messages_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com" xmlns:platformMsgs="urn:messages_2014_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
            <platformMsgs:record recordType="currency"/>
        </platformMsgs:getAll>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Also we are using the [**node-soap**](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap) module to communicate with this web service and here is what it looks like from that perspective as well.

```
soap.createClient(this.url, function (err, client) {
            client.addSoapHeader({
                passport: {
                    email: 'test@example.com',
                    password: 'pass',
                    account: 'Acct Number',
                    role: {
                        attributes: { internalId: 3 }
                    }
                }
            });
            client.getAll({
                "record": {
                  "attributes": {
                    "recordType": "currency"
                    }
                 }
           }, callback);
        });
});
```

Anyways I hope this helps others as it did stump me for awhile.

Answer (score 1):

NetSuite it's on the version 2015.1 right now, and probably soon will upgrade to 15.2.

This is the last version of the Record Browser, probably don't work for what you are trying to do if you want to get all the records as an object to "for" on them, but you can try to read this records.

https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2015_1/script/record/account.html

Answer (score 0):

Try https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/RecordsBrowser/2013_1/index.html for a list of all supported records and fields in each record.

Comment: But this would need hardcoding each of the record, and as the release version of netsuite changes, the supported records would grow. This will require changing my code every time.
is there an API exposing a method to get all the record types, that would greatly help.
I haven't come across any such API method though, so far!

Comment: People have put the API into easy to read formats, such as http://suitecoder.appspot.com/static/api.html and I understand your comment about the version numbers, but there's not a place that I know of where you are going to get that kind of comprehensive feedback -- without simply participating in the Usergoup and Stack Overflow and reading the release notes every time there's a version release.